# How do I plot a function subject to a constraint?

Tags: plotting, constraint

While learning about Lagrange multipliers, I am finding examples on how a constraint is applied to a function.

Given the following two functions (where E^ is `::e::`):

```
f[x_, y_] := E^(-(3 x^2 + 2 y^2 - x y)/(3))
g[x_, y_] := x^2 + 2*(y + 1/2)^2 - 1
```

And the following constraint:

```
g[x,y]==0
```

I would like to get a plot of the path of the constraint `g[x,y]` over the function `f[x,y]`.

I have tried to plot the function f[x,y] with:

```
f3d = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Which results in:

[image: Function f]

And I would like to see the path of the constrain `g[x,y]==0` over that surface. Similar to this example:

```
ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 4, (x - 1)^2 + y^2 - 7/8}, {x, -2, 
  2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, ContourStyle -> {Automatic, Opacity[0]},
  Mesh -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {Green, Thick, Dashed}}]
```

[image: Example]

But I can not get that plot. I have tried this but I am missing the condition `g[x,y]==0` which I do not know how to add:

```
ContourPlot3D[f[x, y] == g[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Try]

In 2D is easier as you can draw both contour plots and then combine, but in 3D I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `MeshFunction`

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, g[x, y]], Mesh -> {{0}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Or to retain original mesh, `Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &, Function[{x, y}, g[x, y]]}, Mesh -> {15, 15, {0}}, MeshStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Directive[Red, Thick]}]`

Answer (score 8):

- Or use `RegionFunction` and only display it's boundary.

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, g[x, y] <= 0], 
 BoundaryStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> None, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

- Or still use `ContourPlot3D`.

```
ContourPlot3D[{z - f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 
  2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> {Automatic, None}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {2 -> None, {1, 2} -> {Green, Thick, Dashed}}]
```

[image]

- `ImplicitRegion` also work.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{z == f[x, y], 
    g[x, y] == 0}, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}}];
Region[Style[reg, Directive[Thick, Red]], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that helps to understand well how plots work.